# Chrome speed tracer only allowed on developer's build or not?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome

is the speed tracer only allowed on the developer's build?

I'm using the "normal" build and i've installed speed tracer. It "seems" to be working but I want to be sure and don't want it to corrupt my files or cause my computer to crash or something

Although the speed tracer page at http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/ does not indicate that we need a developer's build, from past experience I do know it certainly used to need the developers build.

So basically is there an "official document" that says the speed tracer has upgraded from developers-build-only to everyone? Or do I risk crashing my browser by using that unsafe extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Speed Tracer Extension Page](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/) doesn't say anything about needing a specific build.  I think you'll be fine.  Also, I had no idea this even existed, and this looks really useful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know it certainly used to need the developers build in the past but I don't know if it still does!

Comment: i know that too.. hence the question